# ATM Machine C language

Tags: c

So I have to make an ATM machine program for my Intro to C programming class and I'm getting kinda frustrated. My professor just emailed us saying this: "Under NO circumstances should you declare any pointers. You are provided the pointers you will need to use and those are the function arguments. They should not be re-declared in the functions or in the  main function.

You alos need to actually READ the comment I wrote with the assignment. Most (or all ) of you will need to add an argument to the withdrawal function because, to do it correctly, you will need access to the type of account."

I tried not declaring the pointers in the main function but I'd get errors. I also am not sure if I should be using if/else instead of switch, cause every time it asks me if I'd like to do another transaction the program closes no matter which (1, 2, 3) I select.

My last problem is I don't know how to go about updating the amount of money in the selected account when making a transaction. (currball) is confusing...

I really appreciate any help I can get.

```
//  main.c
//  Project Assignment 2
//
//  Created by Paul Gleichman on 2/22/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Paul Gleichman. All rights reserved.
//

#include <stdio.h>

//* Displays the list of user’s options available
//** Displays the user’s selections and sets the value of the choice
void mainMenu(int *choice);

//Prompts the user for the amount of their deposit and updates the selected account
void DepositMoney( double *currBal);

//Asks the user if they want another transaction
void Repeat(char * doAgain);


//Displays the types of account they would like to access and sets the
//value of the chosen account type
void AccountMenu( char *typeAcct);

//Prompts the user for the amount of the withdrawal, determines if there are
//sufficient funds and updates the selected account if funds are dispensed
void WithdrawMoney( double *currBal);

//Displays the user’s current account balance for the selected account
void ShowBalance( double currBal);

int main()
{
    double preBal = 4325;
    double checking = 575;
    double savings = 3750;
    double currBal;
    int choice;
    char doAgain;
    char typeAcct;

    //Welcome Screen
    printf("***** Welcome to Legendary Bank ***** \n");

   //Ask user what they'd like to do
    printf("** What would you like to do today? ** \n");

    //List options
    mainMenu(&choice);

    switch (choice) {
        case 1:
            AccountMenu(&typeAcct);
            DepositMoney(&currBal);
            Repeat(&doAgain);
            break;
        case 2:
            AccountMenu(&typeAcct);
            WithdrawMoney(&currBal);
            Repeat(&doAgain);
            break;
        case 3:
            AccountMenu(&typeAcct);
            ShowBalance(currBal);
            Repeat(&doAgain);

    }

}

//*Displays the list of user’s options available
//**Displays the user’s selections and sets the value of the choice
void mainMenu(int *choice)
{
    printf("1 - DEPOSIT \n");
    printf("2 - WITHDRAWAL \n");
    printf("3 - CHECK ACCOUNT BALANCE \n");
    printf("Important: ");
    printf("To transfer money first select \n(2) for WITHDRAWAL, then \n(1) for DEPOSIT\n");
    scanf(" %d", choice);
}

//Prompts the user for the amount of their deposit and updates the selected account
void DepositMoney( double *currBal)
{
    printf("How much would you like to deposit?:  \n");
    scanf(" %lf", currBal);
    printf("Thank you, please take your receipt.\n");
}

//Asks the user if they want another transaction
void Repeat(char * doAgain)
{
    int choice;
    printf("Would you like to make another transaction?\n");
    printf("(Y)es / (N)o ? \n");
    scanf(" %c", doAgain);
    do {
        mainMenu(&choice);
    } while (doAgain == 'Y' || doAgain == 'y');
}

//Displays the types of account they would like to access and sets the
//value of the chosen account type
void AccountMenu( char *typeAcct)
{
    printf("Please select account: \n");
    printf("Choose C for Checking\n");
    printf("Choose S for Savings\n");
    scanf(" %c", typeAcct);
}

//Prompts the user for the amount of the withdrawal, determines if there are
//sufficient funds and updates the selected account if funds are dispensed
void WithdrawMoney( double *currBal)
{
    printf("How much would you like to withdraw?\n");
    scanf(" %lf", currBal);
    printf("Thank you, please take your cash and receipt\n");
}

//Displays the user’s current account balance for the selected account
void ShowBalance( double currBal)
{
    printf("You have %lf in your account\n", currBal);
}
```

Comment: "I tried not declaring the pointers in the main function but I'd get errors"  -- what errors?  While running or compiling?  Your `main()` as posted looks sane without pointers.  "every time it asks me if I'd like to do another transaction the program closes no matter which (1, 2, 3) I select." -- this is because `main()` has no flow control which reacts to changes in `doAgain`'s value.

Comment: Change `while (doAgain == 'Y' || doAgain == 'y');` by `while (*doAgain == 'Y' || *doAgain == 'y');`. Otherwise it won't compile. And `currBal` is not initialized.

Comment: I'd get errors while writing the code (using Xcode). I tried doing what Michael suggested but it would cause it to loop no matter which option I chose, it wouldn't continue, it'd just ask which option I'd like to proceed with over and over...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do something like this. edited your main and repeat function

```
int main()
{
double preBal = 4325;
double checking = 575;
double savings = 3750;
double currBal;
int choice;
char doAgain =0;
char typeAcct;

//Welcome Screen
while(1){
printf("***** Welcome to Legendary Bank ***** \n");

//Ask user what they'd like to do
printf("** What would you like to do today? ** \n");

//List options
mainMenu(&choice);
    do{
       switch (choice) {
          case 1:
             AccountMenu(&typeAcct);
             DepositMoney(&currBal);
             Repeat(&doAgain);
             break;
           case 2:
             AccountMenu(&typeAcct);
             WithdrawMoney(&currBal);
             Repeat(&doAgain);
             break;
           case 3:
             AccountMenu(&typeAcct);
             ShowBalance(currBal);
             Repeat(&doAgain);
           default :
             printf("invalid Choice");
             Repeat(&doAgain);
       }
    }while(doAgain == 'Y');
printf("//////////////////NEW TRANSACTION//////////////\n")
}
return 0;
}
```

in your repeat function

```
void Repeat(char * doAgain)
{
int choice;
printf("Would you like to make another transaction?\n");
printf("(Y)es / (N)o ? \n");
scanf(" %c", doAgain);
}
```

Comment: Awesome, this fixed the program ending on the second transaction. Appreciate the help!